# playOrm using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playorm

For starters, and granted being new to java development, I have a few questions.

I am using the Eclipse IDE, and have downloaded a zip file *com.alvazan.orm library.

Initializing a Java Project from an Existing Ant Buildfile, and using the build.xml file, I get TONS of com.alvazan.orm.api packages, each containing various .java files/test cases and and equal number of .Jar files containing even more packages, etc.

So, right off the bat, I notice several warnings, **Java Build Problems**

1. Classpath variable 'JRE_LIB' in project 'std_buildfile' is deprecated: Use the JRE System Library instead

Is this something that will effect the running and debugging of test cases?

Additionally, I have run into **Java Problems**, upon initial build:

1. The method translateToColumnImpl(Collection, RowToPersist, Collection) from the type DboColumnToManyMeta is never used locally
2. The value of the local variable existing is not used
3. The value of the local variable toBeAdded is not used
4. The value of the local variable toBeRemoved is not used

While these are currently only errors, since attempting to run various test cases and coming up with even more warnings and errors, I am concerned the looming warnings maybe affecting the outcome.

Please advise if this something which needs addressing or if is generally a common occurrence.

I would be glad to post more information of necessary, just let me know what is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "warnings" not errors are a common occurence.  You only have issues when you see the red errors.   Eclipse likes to tell you about potential problems like generally unused fields should be deleted.  Many times fields are not deleted because they are about to be used.  None of the warnings ever affect your ability to run or debug the programs though.  ONLY the red errors will affect your run AND when you try to run in eclipse with red warnings eclipse will even prompt you saying "this doesn't even compile, are you sure you still want to run" and generally you should not run when you have red errors.